# Issue getting 64 bit conversion iOS

Tags: xcode, 64-bit

I am working on existing application, integrating the new 64 bit support third party framework. While passing new static vector version-8 length is causing issue, it's giving length is wrong. If same code running it on new Xcode project it's fine.
So i need to change any other settings?

As of now the my project settings:[image]

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem exactly. Could you explain with more details?